Display data in file column dynamically
In my Canvas Power App, I have an attachment control that lets me upload files to a file column ('RequestedFile') in a table (Tasks). I am only considering the case where the uploaded is an Excel-file.
What I want to do now is the following: I want to insert a Gallery of the tasks (GalleryTasks) and display the corresponding files to a chosen task inside the Canvas App.
I tried to do this via the usual approach using a Gallery and showing
GalleryTasks.Selected.RequestedFile.
This approach does not work since it only shows the name of the files. How can I accomplish that I have a view of the actual file contents? Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
